# How can I re-write my Regex Expression to begin the search at the occurrence of a separate pattern?

Tags: python, regex

Apologies if this is a duplicate - I wasn't exactly sure what to search for and everything I found came up short.
I'm using Python and if anybodies interested I drafted up a quick example on here:
[Regex101 Example I created](https://regex101.com/r/farWSL/1)

I'm trying to use regex to grab the first part of a string that might be formatted like so:

```
**This is a Location** 8:20
```

or it could be formatted like...

```
Irrelevant information - **Relevant Information** 6:90
```

I wrote the following expression which does the job almost perfectly, pulling the relevant part of the string (words) out but it also pulls in the second part of the string (numbers). This is annoying as I then need to do a second regex/python expression to split that out.

```
r'(\w* ){1,5}\d+:\d+'
```

I'm using Python so I know I can quite easily separate the info manually with a slice etc but I feel like there must be a more elegant solution to my Regex that would negate the need for this step. Essentially I think the solution would be to match `'\d+:\d+'` and look back from there.

Comment: Use a positive lookahead `\b[a-zA-Z ]+(?=\s\d+:\d+)`

Answer (score 0):

Ok - perhaps this isn't the most elegant solution but I've just realised I think I can use capturing groups like so:

```
# Pattern with groups
pattern = '((\w* ){1,5})(\d+:\d+)'
string = "useless something else - useful 2:2"

r = re.search(pattern, string)

if r:
    useful info= r.group(1)
    boundary = r.group(3)
```

Theoretically, I'm always going to have the same number of groups with group 1 containing the relevant string I'm trying to grab and group 3 the time/number value. I'll test this now and update/close this thread.